# O processo não pode acessar o arquivo porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo

Tags: c#

O problema aparece na penúltima linha do código abaixo, o que posso fazer? Obs: já tentei também usar o "Using" nos StreamReader, mas não resolveu.

```
        string CJ;
        string CJ1;
        string CJ2;
        StreamReader LJ = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\Jo\" + cbJ.Text + ".ij");
        {
            CJ = LJ.ReadLine();
            LJ.Close();
        }
        StreamReader L1 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\Ja\" + cbJ1.Text + ".jad");
        {
            CJ1 = LJ1.ReadLine();
            LJ1.Close();
        }
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(CJ, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(CJ, CJ1 + "/" + cbJ.Text), true);
        }
        StreamReader L2 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\Ja\" + cbJ2.Text + ".jad");
        {
            CJ2 = LJ2.ReadLine();
            LJ2.Close();
        }
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(CJ, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(CJ2 + "/" + cbJ.Text, CJ), true);
        }
```

Comment: Ponha uns nomes mais claros nas variáveis que ajuda a localizar o problema. Você cria L1, mas fecha LJ1, cria L2, mas fecha LJ2, dificil acompanhar o código assim.

Comment: Na verdade o código poderia ser bem mais simples que isso, o que evitaria esse erro.

Comment: Se tem uma nova dúvida, faça uma nova pergunta, não altere a resposta dessa forma que muda completamente a pergunta. Você tinha um problema e ele foi resolvido. Se ainda não resolveu tudo, pode fazer novas perguntas.

Comment: Faça o seguinte Carlos, poste esse código novo como uma pergunta nova, já que passamos dessa etapa, e explique na nova como está o diretório e como é pra ficar depois da função, que a gente tenta ajudar. Procure dar mais detalhes, não só o código, e com exemplos de como você gostaria do diretório antes e depois.

Answer (score 3):

Se o código é so esse mesmo, é erro de digitação. Veja a diferença nas variáveis `LJ1` e `LJ2`:

```
    string CJ;
    string CJ1;
    string CJ2;
    StreamReader LJ = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\Jo\" + cbJ.Text + ".ij");
    {
        CJ = LJ.ReadLine();
        LJ.Close();
    }
    StreamReader L1 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\Ja\" + cbJ1.Text + ".jad");
    {
        CJ1 = L1.ReadLine();
        L1.Close();
    }
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(CJ, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(CJ, CJ1 + "/" + cbJ.Text), true);
    }
    StreamReader L2 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\Ja\" + cbJ2.Text + ".jad");
    {
        CJ2 = L2.ReadLine();
        L2.Close();
    }
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(CJ, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(CJ2 + "/" + cbJ.Text, CJ), true);
    }
```

Agora, se você explicar o que quer fazer, melhor, pois provavelmente mesmo corrigindo tudo que precisa, o código acima está muito confuso e provavelmente com coisa que nem precisaria para atingir seu objetivo.

Talvez te interesse isso aqui:

```
LJ = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + @"\Jo\" + cbJ.Text + ".ij")).First();
L1 = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + @"\Ja\" + cbJ1.Text + ".jad")).First();
L2 = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + @"\Ja\" + cbJ2.Text + ".jad")).First();
```

Sobre o `Application.StartupPath`, precisa ver se é isso mesmo que quer. Foge do problema da pergunta, mas sugiro estudar direitinho como funciona, para ver se numa situação real é a melhor forma de obter o caminho que precisa.

Comment: Simplificando: copiar do LJ para o L1 e depois copiar do L2 para o LJ, substituindo automaticamente arquivos com mesmo nome. Sobre o Application.StartupPath: sim, preciso dessa informação na raiz do software. Sobre a simplificação do código: obrigado, isso serve muito, sou novo em C# e não sabia o quanto poderia ter tornado mais simples o código.

Comment: Ele consegue copiar do LJ pro L1, o problema aparece na cópia do L2 pro LJ.

Comment: Fiz do jeito que você disse (verifique novamente a pergunta) mas o problema persiste no segundo File.Copy, onde pego os arquivos do 3 e coloco pro 1, substituindo. Creio que alguma das linhas do meu código está usando o primeiro diretório, permitindo copiar do 1 pro 2, mas impedindo de copiar do 3 pro 1.